# DOM isn't available to JS file, Even after document.ready (.aspx)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In our workplace an old .net developer set us up to use .aspx pages, We have one for each page, as well as a master page

My issue is that inside our master we include a reference to a set of elements which are unique for each page, in the example below it's the tab names for the page we've loaded

For example

Page1.aspx

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="tabContent" runat="server">
    <ul id="tabList">
        <li class-">Custom Tab 1</li>
        <li class-">Custom Tab 2</li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

Page2.aspx

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="tabContent" runat="server">
    <ul id="tabList">
        <li class-">Custom Tab 1</li>
        <li class-">Custom Tab 2</li>
        <li class-">Custom Tab 3</li>
        <li class-">Custom Tab 4</li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

Page3.aspx

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="tabContent" runat="server">
    <ul id="tabList">
        <li class-">Custom Tab 123</li>
        <li class-">Custom Tab 456</li>
        <li class-">Custom Tab 789</li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

MasterPage.aspx

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabMenu" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tabContent" />
    </div>

    <script src="menu_functions"></script>
</body>
```

menu_functions.js

```
function menu_functions(){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Try to do stuff with the <li's> we've defined in each page, but they are never available

        document.getElementByID("tabList"); // Not available, If we set a breakpoint here I can see the tabs are not in the DOM

    )};

    // Window.ready also doesn't work

    // The tabs will get drawn to the DOM after both the document.ready / window.onload events have already fired

}
```

If anyone could explain the correct way to access these elements through clientside JS once they are available in the DOM it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ASP alters id values (sometimes). Do a "view source" in the browser to see what the actual element ids are.

Comment: Right click on the element on one of the items on the page, select "Inspect Element" (might be labeled differently depending on browser). Look for the element in question and see what the actual ids are.

Comment: You could use `ClientIDMode="static"` if needed.